# Form element closing too soon

Tags: php, html

I have a PHP script which generates a table with each row (supposedly) as a form. The table is generating very nicely, but for some reason the form tag is closing immediately. I have no idea why and it's making my cranky. Any ideas?

```
echo '
 <form method="post" action="#" id="status_row_'.$row["name"].'">
 <tr class="even">
      <input type="hidden" name="category" id="category" value="'.$category[0]['category'].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="error_level" id="error_level" value="'.$row['level'].'">
      <input type="hidden" name="service_name" id="service_name" value="'.$row['name'].'">
      <td class="status-icons" name="error_circle"><div class="'.$error_circle.'"></div></td>
          //rows deleted here for clarity's sake
                                    </tr></form>'
```

So the Inspect Element on the generated form shows: `<form method="post" action="#" id="status_row_blahblah"></form>` followed by all the rows.

Comment: You are not allowed to place a form tag where you are trying.  The ONLY tags allowed after an opening tr is either th or td.

Comment: @Drew, you also need to follow that up with a `</table>`, and ideally a `</tbody>` tag as well.

Comment: @SableFoste ok, cleared that up and specifically state an opening tr tag

Comment: Updated the code to put the entire <tr> within the form, but it didn't help.  I need multiple forms generated--one for each row of the table.

Comment: @Prix What example?  I don't see one--am I missing it?  There are a bunch of <td> elements that would be part of each form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form element was closing incorrectly because, as some people pointed out, you apparently can't have `<form>` tags in between `<tr>` and `<td>` tags (I don't understand why, but it is what it is).

I found this solution as a workaround:

http://federmanscripts.com/2010/01/12/form-and-table-row-nesting-workaround/

Comment: I saw this workaround.But i was unable to make it work. What did you actually do can you please explain?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember and I no longer have access to that code base.  Any chance you can just use divs styled with `display: table`?  Sorry I can't be of more help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I figured out the way.Thanks again :)

Answer (score 5):

Your html is broken. You're  trying to open a form immediately after the opening `<tr>`, then closing it AFTER the closing `<tr>`. That's illegal html. `<table>` structures cannot be built like that. It should probably be something more like

```
<form>
<table>
<tr>
   <td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Essentially you're trying to stuff your form into the void that exists between `<tr>` and `<td>` tags. Nothing should be there except the table structure:

```
<tr><p>hi there</p><td>go away</td></tr>
```

is illegal, most browsers will render the `<p>` OUTSIDE the table, usually before the opening `<table>` tag. That's why your form is showing up where it is - the browser is attempting to do the best it can with your broken html.

Comment: I need a form for every row of the table.  I've moved the <tr> tags--that was definitely wrong--but I need the form to be within the table.  Is that not possible?

Comment: You can put a form inside any <td> element.

Comment: Then to `<tr><td><form>...</form></td></tr>`.

Answer (score 1):

Are the forms different? Or linked together in some way (i.e. is each table row it's own UNIQUE form with, or is it one giant form with different fields in every row?

If it's the former, then create a form inside each ROW element like so:

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td><form>FORM STUFF GOES HERE</FORM></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><form>FORM STUFF GOES HERE</FORM></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><form>FORM STUFF GOES HERE</FORM></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If it's the latter, or if you only want one form submitted overall, then create the form tags outside the table, and have the form fields within the data cells:

```
<form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>FORM FIELD E.G. TEXT FIELD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FORM FIELD E.G. TEXT FIELD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>FORM FIELD E.G. TEXT FIELD</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Every row should have its own form, with fields defined by columns.  When the user changes data in one row (in any of the fields in that row) that row will update the database for that record only.

Comment: Ok, so try the first code sample I posted as that should do what you want. Another point - you can still accomplish what you'd like using a single form for the entire table, and in your database/update section, you can have a few case/checks to see which form was edited.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are closing the `<tr>` tag before closing the `<form>` tag.